# Can I set timeout for publishing message using bunny gem?

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp

I'd like to publish messages to RabbitMQ using [Bunny](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny) gem. The reason I chose Bunny is ease-of-use compared to [AMQP](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/amqp/).

I can set timeout for subscription ([example](http://bunnyamqp.wordpress.com/2009/08/20/bunny-howto-subscribe-to-a-queue/)). But I couldn't find how to set timeout for publish.

Should I use AMQP gem with [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) instead of using Bunny?

References:

- https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny/blob/master/lib/bunny/channel.rb#L533